Error: Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string
I'm having issues with TypeError in the Next.js API routes folder. I'm receiving the same error over and over again "Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string", but there are no types that have Symbol, nor would it be converted to a string. The only thing I can think of is the error message shown below, but I've tried fixing that and still no luck. Below is /api/email/meetingNotification and is called in a POST using the Fetch API:
/api/email/meetingNotification
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import MeetingNotification from "../../../../../emails/meetingNotification";
import { resend } from '@/utils/resend';

interface EmailData {
    schoolName: string;
    email: string;
    clubName: string;
    meetingDate: string;
    meetingTime: string;
    meetingDescription: string;
    meetingName: string;
    location: string;
    type: string;
    mandatory: boolean;
    meetingId: string;
    clubCode: string;
}

export async function POST(request: Request) {
    const emails: EmailData[] = await request.json();

    try {
        const emailPromises = emails.map(({
         schoolName,
         email,
         clubName,
         meetingDate,
         meetingTime,
         meetingDescription,
         meetingName,
         location,
         type,
         mandatory,
         meetingId,
         clubCode
         }: EmailData) => {
            return resend.emails.send({
                from: `${clubName} <${clubCode}@clubcentric.org>`,
                to: email,
                subject: `A new meeting has been scheduled for ${clubName}`,
                react: MeetingNotification({
                    schoolName,
                    location,
                    type,
                    clubName,
                    meetingDate: new Date(meetingDate).toDateString(),
                    meetingId,
                    meetingTime,
                    meetingDescription,
                    meetingName,
                    mandatory,
                })
            });
        });

        await Promise.all(emailPromises);

        return NextResponse.json({ status: 'Ok' }, { status: 200 });
    } catch (e: unknown) {
        console.error('Failed to send emails:', e);
        return NextResponse.json(
            { error: 'Internal server error. Please try resending the emails.' },
            { status: 500 }
        );
    }
}

sendMeetingNotification();
        if (meetingData.meeting_data.push_notification) {
            const { data: membershipsData, error: membershipsError } = await supabase
                .from('memberships')
                .select('user_id')
                .eq('club_id', userId);

            if (membershipsError) {
                console.error('Error fetching memberships:', membershipsError.message);
                toast.error("There was an error: Memberships Unavailable")
                return;
            }

            const emails = [];

            for (const member of membershipsData) {
                const { data: userDirectoryData, error: userDirectoryError } = await supabase
                    .from('user_directory')
                    .select('email')
                    .eq('user_id', member.user_id);

                if (userDirectoryError) {
                    console.error('Error fetching user directory:', userDirectoryError.message);
                    toast.error("There was an error: User Directory Unavailable")
                    continue;
                }

                for (const members of userDirectoryData) {
                    emails.push({
                        schoolName: clubSchool,
                        email: members.email,
                        clubName: clubName,
                        meetingDate: selectedDate?.toISOString(), 
                        meetingTime: `${startTime} - ${endTime}`,
                        meetingDescription: meetingData.meeting_data.description,
                        meetingName: meetingData.meeting_data.title,
                        mandatory: meetingData.meeting_data.mandatory,
                        clubCode: clubCode,
                        location: meetingData.meeting_data.location,
                        type: selectedType,
                        meetingId: meetingData.meeting_id,
                    });
                }
            }

            // Send POST request to the endpoint
            const response = await fetch('/api/email/meetingNotification', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(emails),
            });

            if (!response.ok) {
                console.error('Failed to send emails:');
                toast.error("Notification System Error!")
            } else {
                console.log('Emails sent successfully');
                router.push("/dashboard/club/meetings")
            }
        } else {
            console.log('Push notifications are disabled: Emails not sent!');
        }
    }

Any help would be appreciated!
I've tried asking Claude and other AI to find a solution, they haven't been able to. Additionally, I've searched everywhere for any Symbol types, but there are none. This is the error message:
Failed to send emails: TypeError: Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string
    at _ (/Users/musamalik/Downloads/[redacted]/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:254562)
    at Object.get (/Users/musamalik/Downloads/[redacted]/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:254683)
    at Proxy.toString (<anonymous>)
    at MeetingNotification (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./emails/meetingNotification.tsx:319:93)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/app/api/email/meetingNotification/route.ts:19:95)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at POST (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/app/api/email/meetingNotification/route.ts:14:38)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async /Users/musamalik/Downloads/[redacted]/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:63251


Could you please create an example where we can test out your code using CodeSandBox? It's nearly impossible to debug this with the information that you provided.

This doesn't seem to be a [mre] others can use to demonstrate the issue for themselves; if you can't provide this then it might be closed as "needs debugging details".

Hi guys, I’ll create a CodeSandbox, I wasn’t sure if you were able to gain information from the code provided!

You showed api/email/meetingNotification but you didn't show emails/meetingNotification.tsx and how Proxy was used

Do not add "Solved" to the title. If you have a solution, you can post it as an answer to help future visitors.

I actually don’t even know how I solved it, I rewrote all my email code and it fixed itself. It might have been the globalUrl variable.
